# StateListDrawable padding

Tags: android, padding, drawable, android-selector

I have problem with padding in StateListDrawable.
If for some  in my styles i define reference on some `<selector>` with image resources, it set some wrong padding for my 9path images. By the way i set particular image - all is ok. But otherwise, android create `StateListDrawable` for my `<selector>` and (as i saw by using debugger on sources) it get padding by use method:

```
Rect getConstantPadding();
```

and return wrong values (in my case it not null or 0).
This method use mVariablePadding variable:

```
if (mVariablePadding) {
     return null;
}
```

But i can't set it false in resources (maybe i did something wrong).

**Does someone know solution for this problem? Thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in 9-path images. For selector it calculate padding from right-bottom border (content) of nine-path drawable. 
Beside there is variables in selector `android:variablePadding`, that calculate that padding (choose the biggest, etc). So it can be still non 0, even if in mostly cases images doesn't have padding.